# Quadrilateral with Inscribed circle

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Suppose quadrilateral $ABCD$ has an inscribed circle with radius $r$, if we know $AB=a,\angle A=\alpha, \angle B=\beta$, how to find the $BD$ and $AC$?

Comment: can you post a picture please?

Answer (score 2):

We clearly cannot, there are too many solutions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we get $$\overline{BD}^2=r^2+r^2-2r^2\cos(2\alpha)$$
$$\overline{AC}^2=r^2+r^2-2r^2\cos(2\beta)$$
by the Theorem of cosines

Comment: $BD$ and $AC$ **are not** fixed by $r,\alpha$ and $\beta$ only.